# Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager with blob data type

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

i tried to create an edit form which is include a blob data type in it. but somehow,when i run the project, i got an error, " `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "car.jpg" to class "java.sql.Blob" for attribute "images": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager` " .

what does it mean?

does it because of the setProperty tag in the jsp?

`<%@page import="b.ItemDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="u" class="b.ItemBean"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="u"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="images" name="u" /><br>`

can anyone please help me with this error? thanks in advance !